# Print messages in PyCUDA

Tags: cuda, pycuda

In simple CUDA programs we can print messages by threads by including cuPrintf.h but doing this in PyCUDA is not explained anywhere. How to do this in PyCUDA?

Comment: http://wiki.tiker.net/UsingPrintf

Comment: But is there any way with cuPrintf.h?

Comment: @talonmies Doesn't work out of the box on a Tesla C2070. Any ideas as to why?

Comment: Updated link: http://wiki.tiker.net/PyCuda/Examples/UsingPrintf. In short, #include <stdio.h> and then use printf().

Answer (score 5):

On Compute Capability 2.0 and later GPUs, `cuPrintf.h` is discouraged in favor of just using CUDA's built-in printf().  To use it, just `#include <stdio.h>` and call `printf()` just like on the host.

The PyCUDA wiki has a [specific example of this](http://wiki.tiker.net/PyCuda/Examples/UsingPrintf).